# Questions about real-valued measure on a vector space.

Tags: measure-theory, representation-theory

I am reading the [lecture notes on representation theory](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~kazhdan/). I have some difficulty in solving Exercise 1.8 on page 4. Let $K$ be a non-archimedian local field and $v : K \to Z \cup \{\infty \}$ a valuation. 
Let $L$ be a one-dimensional $K$-vector space. Let $||L||$ the one-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-vector space $(L − {0}) \times \mathbb{R}/K^*$, where $a \in K^*$ acts on $(L − {0}) \times \mathbb{R}/K^*$ by $a(l, r) = (al, ||a^{−1}|| r)$, $||a^{−1}|| =q^{-v(a^{-1})}$.
Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional $K$-vector space of dimension $d$. How to show that (1) we can identify the real line $||Λ^d (V^∨)||$ with the line of real-valued invariant measures on $V$ and (2) $||Λ^d (V^∨ )|| \otimes ||Λ^d (V )|| = \mathbb{R}$? Thank you very much. Suppose that $V^{\vee} = <\alpha_1^{\vee}, \ldots, \alpha_d^{\vee}>$. Then $\Lambda^d(V^{\vee})=k \alpha_1^{\vee} \Lambda \ldots \Lambda \alpha_d^{\vee}, k \in K$ is a one dimensional $K$-vector space.